# Rollingback an update command in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

Kindly note I just started developing a month ago and self taught so bear with me here. First when I check mariadb's status there is this warning:innodb rollback segment(s) are active. I would like to rollback an update command is that still possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Once `COMMITted` or `autocommitted`, you cannot rollback.